# opencv runs in python but not in spyder

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am a complete beginner to `opencv`. I wrote this code in spyder and it shows no module named **'cv2'**

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('D:\ML\img1.jfif',1)
cv2.imshow('D:\ML\img1.jfif',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but the same code works in the python cmd

any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can you check if the python interpreter you execute from the command line is the same used in spyder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why this could be the case.

1. May you work in a virtual environment in which your cv2 package is not "known".
2. You have the wrong cv2 package for your python version.
3. Maybe you use the wrong interpreter (eg. if you have a python2 and python3 interpreter but pip installed cv2 for the wrong one).

Plase provide which python interpreter you have set up for your Spyder, if this is the only installed python on your path and how you installed cv2.

Best regards and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I uninstalled everything and trying to install everything from scratch because I am unable to locate python on my machine. cmd shows its in app data and is very difficult to navigate. I will make custom folders in C drive and then follow these instructions

Comment: I ditched Anaconda and installed visual studio code with normal python. Its working flawlessly

Comment: @PeddintiKartik If you found anything which solved your problem please mark it accordingly for other users. For the future please provide all informations which might help to find a solution correctly and complete, so that others may use it for similiar problems. E.g. give the information that you used Anaconda or python(x,y) if that is the case, since this might be relevant. Usually I would suggest to install python from the python webpage, use an IDE of your choice and use PIP to install packages, since you have more control over what you actually did.

Comment: @Earl I did exactly the same and its working great. I accepted the solution. On that day I forgot to accept it

Answer (score 0):

Probably a diffent Python interpreter / executable for each case:

You can check:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```